# Helm Chart configmap from yml file

Tags: configmap, kubernetes-helm

I created ConfigMap in helm

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
    {{- $root := . -}}
    {{- range $path, $bytes := .Files.Glob "*.yml"}}
    {{ $path }}: '{{ $root.Files.Get $path }}'
    {{- end }}
```

When I run kubectl get configmaps, the yml file format changed to a different file format adding "\" to the yml file. How can I prevent helm from changing the file format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
    {{- $root := . -}}
    {{- range $path, $bytes := .Files.Glob "*.yml"}}
    {{- $value := $root.Files.Get $path -}}
    {{- printf "\n" | nindent 2 -}}
    {{ $path | nindent 2 }}: {{- toYaml $value | nindent 4 }}
    {{- end }}
```

You can use something like above.

#### What I've done:

- save the file content in `$value` variable.
- later pass `$value` variable to `toYaml` function and `nindent` with 4
- use toYaml template function, so that helm doesn't change the file content.

Comment: Thank you @Abu Hanifa. It worked. I really appreciate your solution.